# Change select Name Suffix to input in shipping address: Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to change select Name Suffix to input in shipping address Magento 2? I want to change it, but I don't know where I can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the Select name suffix by following the below steps on the Live.

1. Go to Magento Admin > Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customers Configuration.
2. Find the "Name and Address" option on the page.
3. Select "Show Prefix" from the given options (Optional and Required).
4. You can add more prefix in "Prefix Dropdown Options" by adding Semicolon (;) separated values or leave empty for the open text field.

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: thank you, but i need chang it from drop down -> input text

Comment: Please check 4th point in the answer to make it text field.

Comment: thanks <3 have a nice day